# A question related to divisibility

Tags: divisibility

Given that $2n + 1$ is divisible by $3$, and $n$ is a natural number, what form can $n$ take? As per the solution I am referring to, $n$ must in the form $3k+1$, where $k$ is a whole number. The solution further adds that it is equivalent to $6p + 1$ or $6p + 4$.

While the answer makes sense when plugged into the expression $2n+1$, is there a generic set of steps to arrive at this answer? I probably seem to be missing something obvious :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Odd multiple of $3$ can be written as $3(2k+1)=6k+3$

$$2n+1 = 6k+3$$

$$2n = 6k +2$$

$$n=3k+1$$

Exercise:

> Explore what happens when $n=2p$.
>
> Explore what happens when $n=2p+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $2n+1 = 3k$ modulo 2. Then $1 = k$ modulo 2, so $k = 2k'+1$, so $2n+1 = 3k = 6k' + 3$. So $2n+1  =6k' + 3$ which implies $2n = 6k' + 2$ or $n = 3k' + 1$.

so $n$ itself must be a multiple of 3 plus 1.

Also: all odd numbers that are multiples of 3, are of the form multiples of 6 plus 3.

Answer (score 0):

While there are different ways of approaching this, as described in other two answers, I found Remainder theorem approach easy to follow.

Given that $2n + 1$ is divisible by 3,

$Rem (\frac{2n + 1}{3}) = 0$ $=>$ $Rem (\frac{2}{3})*Rem (\frac{n}{3}) + Rem (\frac{1}{3}) = 0$. solving this, we get $Rem (\frac{n}{3}) = 1$. Hence $n$ can take the form $3k + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=3m+r$, with $0\le r<3$; then
$$
2n+1=6m+2r+1\equiv2r+1\pmod 3
$$
Thus we have $2r+1\equiv 0\pmod{3}$. Therefore $r\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ (prove it). Also the converse holds (prove it).

In order to find the other form of the answer, distinguish between $m$ even or odd.